# Ionic 4 - Simple Login with localStorage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am new to ionic and jumped onto the beta Ionic 4 apologies if I ask the simplest question. I've implemented a simple login and I am storing the returned user object from my REST api using Ionic `Storage` like this (in `user.service.ts`):

```
var url = `${this.APIUrl}/api/Account/Get?email=${login.email}&password=${login.password}&apikey=${this.APIKey}`;

this.CurrentUser = await this.http.get<iUserModel>(url).toPromise();

// Store User Details
this.storage.set("CurrentUser", this.CurrentUser);
```

If I investigate in my browser I can see that it is stored under Indexed DB:
[image]

Now my challenge is to check if user is logged in on my home page. I've tried to use both the `constructor` and `ngOnInit()` but it seems my `home.page.html` is rendering before the call to go fetch user is complete and here is how I've done it (in `home.page.ts`):

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit 
{
  CurrentUser: any;

  constructor(private nav:NavController, private auth: UserService, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private menuCtrl: MenuController) 
  {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);

    this.APIUrl = this.auth.APIUrl;
    this.CurrentUser = this.auth.CurrentUser; // This becomes undefined when page is refreshed whilst LIVE testing in the browser
  }

  ngOnInit() 
  {
    /*if (this.auth.GetUser() == undefined || (this.auth.GetUser() != undefined && this.auth.GetUser().Id <= 0))
    {
      this.nav.navigateBack("/login");
    }*/

    this.SetUser();
  }

  async SetUser()
  {
    await this.auth.GetUser();

    this.CurrentUser = this.auth.CurrentUser;
  }
 }
```

In `user.service.ts`:

```
async GetUser() 
{
    this.storage.get("CurrentUser").then( (user) =>
    {
      this.CurrentUser = user;
      console.log(user);
    });
}
```

My `console.log(user)` does indeed produce results, however when I try to access the `CurrentUser` that should now be set in my home.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Sample Project
    </ion-title>
    <ion-avatar end>
      <img [alt]="CurrentUser.DisplayName" [src]="APIUrl + '' + CurrentUser.Selfie" />
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

it is always undefined. Can anyone please point out what step I am missing?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is CurrentUser really always undefined or does it become a value later on?

You could also take a look at [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#predefined-tokens-and-multiple-providers) to make angular wait with bootstraping if you want to postpone the rendering of the view until a promise has resolved.

Comment: @M4R1KU the CurrentUser does get the value set but only after the view has already been rendered... I will use the suggested approach below or your suggestion, thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M4R1KU mentioned in the comment you can look at [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#predefined-tokens-and-multiple-providers)

But also I can suggest you one solution. I believe you have something like AppComponent (or just App) in your project (try looking at `src/app` folder)

And there you can do something like this:

```
constructor(private platform: Platform, private auth: UserService) {
    this.initializeApp();
}

initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.auth.GetUser();
    });
}
```

Comment: is me checking in EVERY page's `constructor` or `ngOnInit` if `CurrentUser` object is set to determine if user is logged in the best way to check if a user is logged in Ionic? I am coming from a .NET background and would be keen for things such as `[Authorize]` attributes.

Comment: @Morgs if I understand you correctly, you need to check if user is logged in to determine if he can access some page, correct? You can check [guards](https://devdactic.com/ionic-auth-guards/), they will do the job. Also keep in mind that this tutorial is for ionic 3, if you are using ionic 4 you can reference [this article](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-login-angular/)